# I am trying to remove all info between the two brackets on the Spoken line into a separate file

Tags: bash, sed, grep, brackets

I have a file.txt that contains some values. I am not sure how to extract the info from and between the brackets on a certain line.

The line is Oscar and the info I need to extract is between the brackets

```
Sonia = 0
Oscar = [191, 229, 115, 105, 0, 78, 154, 122, 210, 0]
EnableDebugConsole = true
Ralph = 99
Run = 0
```

It would be grand if I could save the value with and without the brackets so I know in the future. From this website, I gathered some examples and have tried them.

```
grep Oscar file.txt > file_remove.txt
cut -d \= -f 2 file_remove.txt | tr -d " \t\n\r" > file_brackets.txt
cat file_brackets.txt

[191,229,115,105,0,78,154,122,210,0]
```

Even thou it is probably not the nicest way to do it, I still achieved 1 of my goals and I have the info

Now how do I remove the brackets so I can have file_no_brackets.txt that holds just the values between the brackets like so

```
191,229,115,105,0,78,154,122,210,0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it quite simply with `sed`, e.g.

```
$ sed -n '/^Oscar/s/^[^[]*[[]\([^]]*\).*$/\1/p' file
191, 229, 115, 105, 0, 78, 154, 122, 210, 0
```

**explanation**

1. `sed -n` suppress printing of pattern space
2. `/^Oscar/` locate line beginning with `Oscar`
3. `'s/match/replace/` standard `sed` substitution where you match the regex `match` and replace it with `replace`
4. Inside the substitution you have `/^[^[]*` match all chars not a `'['`
5. `[[]` match the `'['`
6. `\([^]]*\)` capture all chars not a `']'` (remaining chars are matched with `.*$`)
7. `replace` is `\1` which is a *back reference* that replaces with the text in the capture group in `6` above.
8. `/p` print the result of the match of `/^Oscar/` and the substitution.

done.

Comment: Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F'\\[|\\]' '/Oscar/{print $2}' file
```

sets field delimiter to right or left square bracket.  Find the line and print the text between first and second field delimiters (that is field 2).

Answer (score 1):

Following awk(s) could also help you in same.

***Solution 1st:*** By using simple search string `Oscar` and using `gsub` utility to globally substitute the things by using regex provided.

```
awk '/Oscar/{gsub(/.*\[|\]/,"");gsub(/, /,",");print}'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** By using simple search of string `Oscar` and then using `match` function of `awk` as follows.

```
awk '/Oscar/{gsub(/, /,",");match($0,/\[.*\]/);if(substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)}}'  Input_file
```

***Solution 3rd:*** Creating field separator as `][` and printing appropriate field which is required.

```
awk -F"[][]" '/Oscar/{gsub(/, /,",",$2);print $2}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `gawk`

```
$ awk 'match($0,/^Oscar.*\[([^]]*)]/,arr){print arr[1]}' infile
```

Test Results:

```
$ cat infile
Sonia = 0
Oscar = [191, 229, 115, 105, 0, 78, 154, 122, 210, 0]
EnableDebugConsole = true
Ralph = 99
Run = 0

$ awk 'match($0,/^Oscar.*\[([^]]*)]/,arr){print arr[1]}' infile
191, 229, 115, 105, 0, 78, 154, 122, 210, 0
```

any awk

```
$ awk '/^Oscar/ && gsub(/^.*\[|\]/,"")' infile
191, 229, 115, 105, 0, 78, 154, 122, 210, 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Only with grep if you want

```
grep "Oscar = \[" file.txt | grep -o [0-9][^]]* >file_no_brackets.txt
```